# Appending a html tag to php variable

Tags: php

I am newbie to php, just starting learning it, while working with wordpress.

I want to add html code to a php variable, a anchor tag link actually. First i splitted the text using `substr()`, and now i want to append a anchor tag at the end of post.

```
$json['timeline']['date'][$i]['text'] =  substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 400)+"<a href='#'>Read more..</";
```

Well, I believe this is not the right way. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Why do you think so? What is the problem you are facing? What should the result be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.` to append strings in PHP. And don't forget to close that tag:

```
$json['timeline']['date'][$i]['text'] = substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 400) . "<a href='#'>Read more..</a>";
```

Note an exception is `echo`, which allows you to pass it arguments separated by commas:

```
echo "one", "two", "three";
```

This has a marginal time advantage, but don't do it because of that (to avoid premature optimisation). In fact, use `.` everywhere in case you end up changing that `echo` to a `return`.

And finally, there's an easier way to add a custom link to an excerpt in Wordpress you might want to look at:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Answer (score 1):

In php you can do this like the way

```
$var = "any value"."<a href='example.com'>link</a>";
```